# Can we create Multiple HttpSessionListeners in a web application

Tags: servlets

I aplication is already having a **`HttpSessionListener`** in which some logic is performed in session created events.

Is it possible to create one more **`HttpSessionListener`**  where I can have some other logic in the same application. ?

Comment: Did you try doing that?

Comment: Yes it seems the only one of them is called.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you also update your **web.xml** like:

```
<web-app>
    ...
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.example.FirstListener</listener-class>
        <listener-class>com.example.SecondListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    ...
</web-app>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am able to load both the Session Listeners.I have added the entry in web.xml but I am not sure why it was not working previously.